# Reload Image if value in EnvironmentObject changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am showing a Card incl. a recipe summary in my app. Via an Edit-Sheet, I am able to change the respecting recipe to a new one. After saving, all the information in the card are updated, but the picture of the old recipe is still shown. Only after I go back and forth in the navigation tree, the picture is updated.

Is there an easy way to tell my ImageLoaderView to reload the picture whenever the value of the recipeVM changes?

```
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import SwiftUI

struct ImageLoaderView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var recipeVM: RecipeViewModel

    let storage = Storage.storage()

    @State private var imageURL = URL(string: "")

    var body: some View {
        WebImage(url: imageURL)
            .resizable()
            .placeholder {
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .indicator(.activity)
            .onAppear(perform: loadImageFromFirebase)
    }

    func loadImageFromFirebase() {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "images/\(recipeVM.recipe.id ?? "").jpg")
        storage.downloadURL { url, error in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            self.imageURL = url!
        }
    }
}
```

For me it looks like the problem is, that the "onAppear" method of the ImageLoaderView is not loaded when coming back from the sheet. So I somehow have to trigger the "loadImageFromFirebase" method whenever the value of "recipeVM" changes. I tried using "didSet" with the var, but this did not work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see `RecipeViewModel`, but I'm going to make an assumption that it looks something like this:

```
struct Recipe {
    var id : UUID
}

class RecipeViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var recipe : Recipe = Recipe(id: UUID())
}
```

(Keep in mind that `recipe` has to be `@Published` for this to work`)

In that case, the you can listen for changes on `recipe` by doing something like this in your `ImageLoaderView`:

```
.onReceive(recipeVM.$recipe) { _ in
  loadImageFromFirebase()
}
```

This can replace your `onAppear`, since it'll get called with the initial value and then again any time it changes.

If you wanted to, you could even refactor this to send the specific recipe into the `loadImageFromFirebase` function:

```
.onReceive(recipeVM.$recipe) { recipe in
  loadImageFromFirebase(recipe: recipe)
}

//....

func loadImageFromFirebase(recipe: Recipe) {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "images/\(recipe.id ?? "").jpg")
        storage.downloadURL { url, error in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            self.imageURL = url!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right about your assumptions and the solution works like a charm. I am actually thinking about moving "loadImageFromFirebase" to the RecipeViewModel. Let me post an update how the turns out.